# How to export/import an Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to export an Android Studio project, and obtain the exported file. Then i want to import this exported file on my other computers so that i can continue to implement the project on different computers. For example, when i create a project, its source codes looks like something like :

https://github.com/serkancay/GorselOgeler

How can i import the resources on the link and run the project without any problem? When i imported these resources a lot of problem occurs although there is no problem in these resources.

I tried many things including creating modules, synronizing, invalidate caches/restart, Build/Edit Conifugurations -> clicked + button ->  Android Application -> i select module and target environment

Answer (score 0):

Due to security you can publish you app like that unless it open source so I recommended use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) as it will keep your repository private  , when you open other pc clone your project and contain your work , dont forget to commit and push your changes to be accessible

for more info read this

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.html